# Get message metadata within rosjava

Tags: ros, timestamp, message, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using rosjava, how would one get the timestamp and other metadata for a message?

Answering in the form of an adaptation of the Listener class in the [rosjava tutorial](http://rosjava.github.io/rosjava_core/latest/getting_started.html) would be particularly useful.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/167806/get-message-metadata-within-rosjava/) by [bradknox](https://answers.ros.org/users/11146/bradknox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2014-05-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After talking with a colleague, I have a rough understanding of this issue now. My understanding is below, though I haven't verified it via further internet research.

Headers are a field type that can be added to a message definition. A pre-defined message cannot simply have a header added to it at runtime (as I thought it could). Because of this, the Message class in rosjava does not have the ability to get the header from the message. Rather, a specific message class that inherits from Message could have a getHeader() method written in for it.

Please feel free to correct any misconceptions here.

---

Originally posted by [bradknox](https://answers.ros.org/users/11146/bradknox/) with karma: 101 on 2014-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0